# Constraint Layout: Button height doesn't match preview

Tags: android

The preview in Android Studio is this:

[image]

The button height looks well.

However, the same page in my phone is this:

[image]

The button's height is different from what I saw in Android Studio Preview. Why?

Here is the xml:

activity_chat.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="ocm.my.chat.View.ChatActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/chat_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:title="fsdasdfsda"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_chat"/>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_chat.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                             app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    >


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/msg_type"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:hint="Input message"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_chat_send"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/list_msg"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_chat_send"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/background_floating_material_dark"
        android:text="Send"
        android:textColor="@color/background_material_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/list_msg"
        tools:layout_conversion_absoluteHeight="47dp"
        tools:layout_conversion_absoluteWidth="106dp"
        tools:layout_conversion_absoluteX="262dp"
        tools:layout_conversion_absoluteY="447dp"
        android:layout_width="106dp"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_msg"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        android:layout_height="450dp"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Addition

---

I found that if I use my phone and my friend's phone the button size is abnormal, whereas it's normal run on emulator.

Comment: have you tried using min:Height & max:Height?

Comment: It seems you give the `ListViw` a fixed height so the button will take the remaining space to be its height.

Answer (score 0):

The height of `ListView` is fix, and Button's height depend on `ListView`'s height. So in different screen it will display differently.